# lightning:combobox readonly atrribute is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, platform-bug, read-only, lightning-combobox

According to the [`lightning:combobox` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_combobox.htm) `readonly` should be set to false, but in the markup it renders like this:

```
<input type="text" role="textbox" ... readonly="true" class="slds-input">
```

What oddly doesn't matter, it is always editable. So when I now try to control it myself:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List"
                    default="[{'label': 'Foo', 'value': 'bar'}]"/>

    <lightning:combobox label="" name=""  options="{!v.options}" readonly="true"/>
</aura:application>
```

it results in this error message during rendering:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Assertion
>   Failed!: "readonly" must either be a public property of
>   lightningCombobox or a global HTML attribute : false
>
> Failing
>   descriptor: {MY_NAMESPACE:myApp}

Am I missing something? or is this feature just not properly implemented yet?

### Edit

Half of the attributes of the Options aren't working either!

```
{'label': 'Foo', 'value': 'bar', 'class': 'whatever', 'selected':true}
```

`class` and `selected` are just ignored.

Comment: That looks like a bug. Anyway, looking at the doc this component is supposed to be based on SLDS combobox, but it actually doesn't look like the same at all: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/ You can still try to create a case for that, as it should be working.

Comment: @FabienTaillon Hm weird, you are right, there is no search option or similar. On the right you can select "Readonly", thats what it looks like, but it behaves different.

Comment: Maybe it's a first version with only readonly available (which would explain why you can't change this attribute), but it should be stated in the doc.

Comment: I tried it and am facing the same problem - tried also to downgrade the api version to 40 - the same problem

Answer (score 1):

As  you can read on this [reply](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/220945/69096) a good Idea could be use the disabled attribute.

> readonly is only available in Summer '18 (v43.0). Note that it doesn't
>   seem to work anyways, so you'll probably want to use disabled for
>   right now.