# How to display DualListBox component in readonly mode

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-duallistbox

Specifying a readonly flag in a dualListBox component results in this error

```
Uncaught Assertion Failed!: "readonly" must either be a public property of lightningDualListbox or a global HTML attribute : false

<lightning:dualListbox aura:id="mySelector"
                       name="select things"
                       label="Select"
                       sourceLabel="Options"
                       selectedLabel="Selected"
                       options="{! v.availableItems }"
                       value="{! v.selectedItems }"
                       onchange="{! c.handleItemChange }"
                       readonly="true"/>
```

How do I show the dualListBox in readonly mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readonly` is only available in Summer '18 (v43.0). Note that it doesn't seem to work anyways, so you'll probably want to use `disabled` for right now.